# Calculating Integral of a linear function with respect to a lognormal distributed variable accurately

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I iteratively calculate a fixed point of the following functional equation:

[image]

where h is a know function and Q is a lognormal distribution. Let f* the function solving the functional equation. I know that f(z)*/z is a constant. When calculating f* numerically with Python the ratio f*(z)/z is however monotonically increasing. To quantify the magnitude of the error, I calculate the difference between the last and first point of this ratio.  I think that the source of the problem stems from the numerical integration of the function `f`:

The integral over the function f is taken with respect to a lognormal distribution with stdv `sigma` and mean zero. Numerically, I calculate the integral as follows:

```
integrand = lambda z: f(z) * phi.pdf(z)
result, error = fixed_quad(integrand, int_min, int_max, n=120)
```

The error I calculate is mostly determined by the integration bounds `int_min` and `int_max`. Initially, I specify the integration bounds to be:

```
int_min, int_max = np.exp( - 1 * sigma), np.exp( 1 * sigma)
```

However, when I change the integration bounds to cover 95% of the probability mass of the lognormal distribution, i.e:

```
int_min, int_max = np.exp( - 2 * sigma), np.exp( 2 * sigma)
```

The difference between the highest and lowest point in the ratio f*(z)/z increases by factor 100. The numerical value for the stdv is `sigma = 0.012`.

There are two comments I want to make before stating my question:

1. when I use the function `scipy.quadrature` instead of `scipy.fixed_quad` and define the error tolerance for the integration to be around 1e-8 (the default value of `scipy.quadrature`), the difference between the highest and lowest point in the ratio does not change. Does this indicate that the integration procedure is not the source of the problem after all?
2. The level of the solution f* depends heavily on the integration bounds. The level increases roughly by the factor 3. The change of the levels might be related to the following question posted on Stackoverlow: [Discontinuity in results when using scipy.integrate.quad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003694/discontinuity-in-results-when-using-scipy-integrate-quad)

What other effect could changing the integration bounds might have one the accuracy of the solution to f*?  If the integration routine used can indeed cause the problem, is there a better way to calculate the integral numerically?

Comment: Have you tried using `scipy.integrate.quad` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)?  An adaptive integrator like `quad` should be much more effective than using `fixed_quad`.

Comment: You could also try the `expect` method of `scipy.stats.lognorm` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html).  It uses `scipy.integrate.quad` to compute the integral of `func(x)*lognorm.pdf(x)`, i.e. it takes care of the details for you.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Thank you for your reply. I am trying both of your suggestions right now. I will comment on the results as soon as possible!