# numerically computing convolution when one function is zero over large part of domain

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I am trying to compute the Probability Density Function of a Gaussian convoluted with a LogNormal. The width of the Gaussian is very small compared to the width of the LogNormal, thus the Gaussian is ~0 for much of the integration domain (0, np.inf).

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
def _gaussian(x, mu, sigma):
    return 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2)*np.exp(-1*(x - mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))
def _lognormal(x, mu_log, sigma_log):
    return 1/(x*sigma_log)*1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*np.exp(-1*(np.log(x) - mu_log)**2/(2*sigma_log**2)  )
def _gauss_log(t, x0, mu, sigma, mu_log, sigma_log):
    return  _lognormal(t, mu_log, sigma_log) * _gaussian(x0-t, mu, sigma)

def gauss_log(x,  mu, sigma, mu_log, sigma_log):
        return  [quad(_gauss_log, 0, np.inf, args=(x0, mu, sigma, mu_log, sigma_log))[0] for x0 in x]

x = [ 0.06898463,  0.12137053,  0.21353749,  0.37569469,  0.66099163,
        1.16293883,  2.04605725,  3.59980263,  6.33343911, 11.14295839,
       19.60475495]
y = [0.00000000e+00, 8.31638354e-02, 1.65440428e-01, 4.02998983e-01,
        5.42100908e-01, 4.16612321e-01, 1.72662493e-01, 5.60788435e-02,
        1.43433519e-02, 5.43498669e-03, 2.57428324e-04]
x00 = np.linspace(0.01, 20, 100)

plt.loglog(x, y, 'o')
plt.ylim([0.0001, 10])
plt.plot(x00, gauss_log(x00, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.9))
plt.show()
```

[image: Proper Convolution Integral]

As you can see the integral jumps from a properly computed value to ~0 for some parts where the Gaussian(x) ~ 0. Reading this: [Discontinuity in results when using scipy.integrate.quad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003694/discontinuity-in-results-when-using-scipy-integrate-quad) my thought was that I help the numerical integration by mapping the integration domain from (0, 1) instead of (0, inf) by changing the variable `t`.

------ **EDIT: The original problem was caused by a mistake in my math.** -----

The convolution integral therefore has to be changed to:

`PDF(x) = INT_0^inf F(x,t)dt = INT_0^1 F(x, s/(1-s)) /(1-s)^2 ds`

where `F(x,t)` is the convolution integrand, c.f @Juan Carlos Ramirez answer.

The function `_gauss_log` becomes:

```
def _gauss_log(t, x0, mu, sigma, mu_log, sigma_log):
    return  _lognormal(s/(s-1), mu_log, sigma_log) * _gaussian(x0 - s/(s-1), mu, sigma)/(1-s)**2
```

This fix improves the situation (see picture below: top image not-transformed boundaries, bottom image with transformation), however, the integration still is not satisfactory. How can I solve this issue?

[image: transformed integration boundaries vs. open integral]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement:
`PDF(x) = INT_0^inf F(x,t)dt = INT_0^1 F(x, s) (1+s)^2 ds`
is not quite right, since you need to substitute t as a function of s inside F(x,t). Note that

`t = 1/(1-s) - 1 = s/(1-s)` therefore

```
dt = 1/(1-s)^2 ds
```

and so your transformed integral should be

`INT_0^1 F(x, s/(1-s))/(1-s)^2 ds`

The quad function is quite powerful, but since it basically tries a bunch of different numerical integration techniques it can lack transparency. What if you use the trapezoidal rule to compute the integral from -a to a of lognormal(x-t)gauss(t) by dividing [-a,a] into a uniform grid of N points? Since the gaussian distribution decays superexponentially  You have a lot of control over the error caused by restricting the interval to [-a,a], and similarly you can control how large you want N to be by looking at the error formula (scales quadratically, and you can bound the second derivative of the gaussian*lognormal).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Uniform_grid
This is going to be handwavy, but the trapezoidal rule can have really nice behaviour on rapidly decaying functions, see https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1964-18-087/S0025-5718-1964-0185804-1/S0025-5718-1964-0185804-1.pdf for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, using the trapezoidal rule sounds quite tempting as I have always been struggling with the speed limitations of quad. However, I tried to implement it `x_values = np.linspace(0.1, 10000, 10000)
[np.trapz(_gauss_log(x_values, x0, mu, sigma, mu_log, sigma_log)) for x0 in x]`. This however did not work at all, is my implementation wrong?

Comment: Did you fix your integral transformation to :"INT_0^1 F(x, s/(1-s))/(1-s)^2 ds", as noted above? in particular _gauss_log implementation is incorrect, as you have written it in your question.

Comment: I updated the question so that it reflects your answer, as you can see the change of variables has helped the problem, but did not solve it. I have not yet found time to understand why the version where I compute the integral using np.trapz as mentioned in my last comment does not work.

Comment: When using np.trapz, if you are going to apply it to _gauss_log, you need to specify either the grid x or the grid spacing dx, since the default is to use dx =1 which is too coarse for integration in [0,1] (basically, just two points in your grid!) https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html.

Comment: Oh yes of course! However, when I put :
`def gauss_log(x,  mu, sigma, mu_log, sigma_log):
    x_values = np.linspace(0.001, 1, 10000)
    return  [np.trapz(_gauss_log(x_values, x0, mu, sigma, mu_log, sigma_log), dx=x_values[1]-x_values[0]) for x0 in x]` it still returns an array of nans (assuming the x from the question above...)

Comment: For which values does it return nan? Since the trapezoidal rule is basically just addition and subtraction, i would imagine the problem lies with the evaluation of _gauss_log  at those points (division by 0 and such). Try testing for this. I would just work with the untransformed integral by truncating the integral at [-a,a] and applying trapezoidal rule there.

Comment: super cool, yes now I found my bug. Using the trapz works perfectly now, thanks!